# django creates new object instead of updating

Tags: django, model

I'm currently working on a news website using django and I'm having an issue in updating  categories.

I have created a view that takes the old category name and the new category using a form.

This is my code

```
def update_category(request):

    if request.method=='POST':
        old_name=request.POST.get('old_name').strip() # get old name
        new_name=request.POST.get('new_name').strip() # get new name
        categorie=Category.objects.get(title=old_name) # get category by title (pk)
        categorie.title=new_name # update the title
        categorie.save() # save to the database

return HttpResponseRedirect('/admin/Category_Management)
```

For example, if I try to change category "Technology" to "Computer Science", django creates a new category called "Computer Science" instead of updating "Technology"

This is my category model

```
class Category(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name='Catégorie'
        verbose_name_plural='Catégories'

    title=models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=50,null=False,blank=False,verbose_name='Titre')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title.title()
```

Comment: You have set the primary key of your model to `title`, and are then changing that primary key in your view - when you do this Django will create a new object as it will never overwrite the primary key on the existing row in the database. Primary keys should generally be immutable - you definitely should not use `title` as a primary key if you want to be able to change that value after the object has been created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why did you set title `primary_key=True`? Is there any special reason?

Django automatically create primary key(pk). Check here (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields)

Change your model to below

```
class Category(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name='Catégorie'
        verbose_name_plural='Catégories'

    title=models.CharField(max_length=50,null=False,blank=False,verbose_name='Titre')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title.title()
```

Then you can use your view exactly the same way.

#### p.s.

The pk shouldn't change. If you change your pk and save it again, it will save to other model object. For example,

```
category = Category.objects.get(title='test')
category.id = None
category.title = 'new test'
category.save() # it will make another category, with title 'new test'
```